# Finding a table / view on a database from column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been asked to extract information from a SQL Server database to update a report. I was provided a version of the report that is a few months old; and there's no documentation associated with the report.

The existing data extract has the column names listed, and I've been scouring the SQL Server database by database, table by table, view by view to find the source, to no avail.

There are many tables and views, so I was wondering if I can search for a table / view based on the names of the columns it contains. I'm running SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Information_schema.columns - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql

Comment: Best tool I've found for this is SQL Search from Redgate. It's free. https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIi7y6_qrO2QIVkkwNCh12dgVAEAAYASAAEgJOk_D_BwE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a lot of information from the information_schema views:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES


SELECT  *
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: The Information_Schema.Columns looks promising. I think this contains the data i'll need.

Answer (score 2):

I would go this route:

1) find the table containing your column with this:

```
SELECT c.name AS column_, t.name AS table_ 
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%your_column_name_here%'
```

2) Navigate to the table that contains that field in the object explorer, right click, then select View Dependencies. This will list all objects that reference that table. You can then find any procs/views/etc that possibly produce your data set.

SQL Server also has DMV's that can assist:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities('yourschema.yourtable', 'OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the InformationSchema view

```
SELECT  c.TABLE_NAME,
    c.COLUMN_NAME
FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE   C.COLUMN_NAME IN('ColumnName1', 'ColumnName2')
```